# Convert string to Date SparkR

Tags: datetime, format, sparkr

I'm reading a large dataframe using SparkR. I want to summarize using the month of a column which contains the date in character format:

```
head(select(df, df$booking_date))
  booking_date
1    29-JUL-16
2    29-JUL-16
3    06-JUL-16
4    21-JUL-16
5    28-JUL-16
6    28-JUL-16
```

However, if I try to print the month:

```
head(select(df, month(df$booking_date)))
  month(booking_date)
1                  NA
2                  NA
3                  NA
4                  NA
5                  NA
6                  NA
```

It does not return the correct value. It seems it does not understand the format but executing the following command makes the month() method very unhappy:

```
head(select(df, month(as.Date(df$booking_date, format = "%d/%b/%y")))
```

Thus, how could I get the month from the booking_date column in order to group_by() the data?

Thanks!

Carlos

Answer (score 0):

Try following code to get month name

```
a <- as.list(collect(select(df, df$booking_date)))
b <- SparkR:::lapply(a$booking_date, function(x){months(as.Date(x, format = "%d-%b-%y"))})
print(b)
```